# How can I partition from the right and not the left?

Tags: java, arrays, partition

I'm working on this program that is essentially using the partition algorithm but it's meant to run from the right and not the left. However, I am having problems as it's not running the correct code.
If my array was [64, 17, 7, 3, 33]; when I run partition my output should be [17, 7, 3, 33, 64] but instead I'm getting [33, 17, 7, 3, 64]. Does someone know what the problem is? and How to fix it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PartitionPivotOnRight {

    public static int partition(int[] a) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = a.length - 2;
        int pivot = a.length - 1;

        while (left <= right) {
            while (left < a.length && a[left] < a[pivot])
                ++left;
            while (a[right] > a[pivot])
                --right;
            if (left <= right)
                swap(a, left++, right--);
        }
        swap(a, left, pivot);
        return left;
    }

    public static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 10;
        int[] a = new int[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println(partition(a));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: hi & welcome! `partition` looks ok, but your assumptions are wrong/expectations too high. "Partition" (known from quicksort algorithm) ensures (only) that all elements left to the pivot are lower(equal) and right of the pivot greater(equal)... (and returns the (new) index of pivot element) not more

Comment: ..so, there's nothing to fix: `[5, 3, 8, 9, 12]` is correct output!

Comment: @xerx593 it's not correct since the pivot element is 5 if should order the array so any numbers lower than 5 are to the left of it and any number greater than 5 are to the right of it.

Comment: No, pivot element is last (`12` for the given input)...if you want another pivot, you need to adjust (initialization+ loop)

Comment: `int left=1, right=a.length-1, pivot=0;` could work with same loop

Comment: @xerx593 my problem should not stem from my variables. I have the same code for the Partition of the First element in the Array which makes use of int left = 1; and right = a.length; I have to use int left = 0, right = a.length-2, pivot = a.length-1;

Comment: If you "have to use int left = 0, right = a.length-2, pivot = a.length-1;" how can you say "the pivot element is 5"?

Comment: If you "have to ... pivot = a.length-1;" , then pivot is last element (of a).

Comment: @xerx593 that was my bad I was confused about the algorithm. Since for the first algorithm I have worked on I used the first element as my pivot, but not I'm using the last element as the pivot.

Comment: so we can close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" ? ;)